# "data-dismiss" Bootstrap modal Bugando with position = "absolute"

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a close button by customizing the `modal` bootstrapping.

I want it on the right of `modal` for that I gave a 'position: absolute`or`position: fixed`and modified the`top`and`right` it.

The problem is that in doing so the button becomes unusable. From what I gather, there is a conflict between the `data-dismiss: modal` (attribute that makes the element closing the modal) with the 'position: absolute`.

I tried other ways to make such "button" importing a .svg, create a `<button>`, `<span>` in addition to changing the `position: absolute` by `float: right`.
By doing so, only a small portion of the button area becomes the link to close and not the whole area. Experience in mobile and desktop is pretty nasty as it is necessary to press / click several times to find the right area, and the right is ALL button area to be a link to close the `modal`.

The following code snippet and to become more clear:

```css
.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  /* REMOVE `POSITION` AND THE BUTTON WORKS */
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: transparent;
  right: 35px;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer
}
.close-modal:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}
.lr {
  height: 75px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1051;
}
.rl {
  height: 75px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 1051;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<a href="#modal" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
             CALL MODAL    
</a>



<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
      <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <p>CONTENT MODAL CONTENT MODAL</p>

            <p>CONTENT MODAL CONTENT MODAL</p>

            <p>CONTENT MODAL CONTENT MODAL</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is some another element stacked on top of your close button.
Setting z-index to a high value would make your dismiss button work.
This would make the close-modal button at the top and thus clickable.
You can do this by:

```
.close-modal{
  z-index: 1100;
  position: absolute;
  ...
 }
```